# Динамический цвет точек в scatter plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Пишу визуализацию алгоритма-классификатора knn через sklearn и matplotlb. Последняя функция, которую хотел бы добавить: по нажатию мышки на график отображалась бы точка и предсказывался бы ее класс. Точка отображается, класс предсказывается верно, но цвет точки не меняется (т.е. 0 класс - фиолетовый, 1 - красный и т.д.). Использую цветовую карту. Не могу понять в чем проблема, ведь то же самое сработало раньше, когда я окрашивал фон за точками. Вот функция, которая вызывается при нажатии кнопки мыши:

```py
def onclick(self, event):
        axes = event.inaxes

        if axes is None:
            return

        if (self.dot or self.dot_text) is not None:
            self.dot.remove()
            self.dot_text.remove()

        x = event.xdata
        y = event.ydata

        label, prob = self.knn.get_prediction([[x, y]], prob=True) #предсказание класса и вероятность точности

        self.dot = plt.scatter(x, y, c=label, s=60, #пытаюсь установить цвет точки, как цвет ее класса
                               cmap=self.cmap, edgecolors='black', linewidth=2)
        print(label)

        self.dot_text = plt.text(x, y, 'Класс {0}\n С вероятностью {1}'.format(
            label[0], round(
                            prob[0][int(label[0])], 3
                            )
        ))

        plt.draw()
```

На картинке ниже точка должна быть зеленого цвета, но она всегда фиолетового (что соответствует 0 классу)
[image: Точка должна быть зеленого цвета, но она всегда фиолетового (что соответствует 0 классу)]

---

**UPD:** Спасибо за помощь, прикрепляю исправленный код, если кому-то пригодится.
Исправления коснулись только функции scatter, в нее нужно было добавить нормализацию, а в параметр цвета вместо списка одного элемента labels передавать сам элемент - labels[0].

```py
self.dot = plt.scatter(x, y,
                               s=60,
                               c=int(label[0]),
                               norm=plt.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=self.num_classes-1),
                               edgecolors='black',
                               cmap=self.cmap,
                               linewidth=2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если просто раскрасить точки в  цвета класса и количество классов заранее известно то так:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
x=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
y=[10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18]
label=[0,1,0,2,0,3,0,4,5]
plt.scatter(x, y, 
            c = label,
            cmap = mcolors.ListedColormap(["b", "g","r","y","c","k"]))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если надо использовать свою палитру, то так:

```
plt.scatter(x, y, 
            c = label,
            norm = plt.Normalize(vmin=min(label), vmax=max(label)+1),
            cmap = "nipy_spectral")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А можно как-то использовать встроенную цветовую карту в первом примере?

UPD: добавил norm, как вы и сказали, все еще только один цвет, несмотря на то, что параметр label меняется

Поясню, что добавить мне нужно только одну точку, когда я добавляю массив точек, с ними код, схожий с этим работает прекрасно

Comment: Во-первых, мы не знаем, как вы строите свой "self.cmap". Во-вторых, если х и y-  списки из одного элемента, то и то, что вы передаете в парметр "с" должен состоять из одного элемента. А вот label остаться как минимум списком возможных меток. Пример - в другом ответе.

Comment: self.cmap - это встроенная карта, в данный момент "coolandwarm", x и y - это даже не списки, а просто координаты курсора мыши во время нажатия, а label - предсказанный класс для точки с координатами x, y, т.е. список из одного элмента

Comment: заработало? Ну и чудненько!

Comment: Спасибо вам большое, очень помогли